# Static HTML homepage, Link to WP installation

Tags: html, domain

I need to display a static html homepage at the root domain and have some questions on how to achieve this using WordPress.

The design will have two buttons that will redirect to 2 different sub-folders. One of them will be www.example.com/cats and the other www.example.com/dogs. Since the sub-domain sites will be two different sites, I was planning on installing wp at each of them. My question is, how do I achieve the html homepage at the root domain using WordPress? Keep in mind that I need the html homepage design to show in the root domain.

Effectively it's about hosting an HTML website and a WordPress installation in the same hosting space. Plus linking them together via HTML links.

Comment: Have you considered a multisite install with 2 subdir sites cats and dogs? Note that we are not SEO experts and this is not an SEO stack, nor does SEO have anything to do with this if the end result is always the same. Google doesn't care how you generated your pages, just that they're well formed and fast

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my question. I'm a newbie so just learning as I go. I haven't considered the multi-site option. If using multisite, will I be able to display an html page at the root level? Can this page be powered from one of the wp installations? Thanks again!